# Difference between $\forall A\forall B(\forall C(A\cup C = B\cup C) \rightarrow (A = B))$ and a similar statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between $\forall A\forall B(\forall C(A\cup C = B\cup C) \rightarrow (A = B))$ and $\forall A \forall B \forall C((A\cup C = B\cup C) \rightarrow (A = B))$

I don't exactly get the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference lies in the scope of the quantifier $\forall C$. I show you the scope in both formulas. **edit :** I've added implicit parentheses in red for readability :

$$\forall A \ \forall B \ \Big(\color{red}{\big(}\forall C \ \underbrace{(A\cup C = B \cup C)}_{\textrm{scope }}\,\color{red}{\big)} \to A=B \Big)$$
This first formula holds since, once $A$ and $B$ have been picked, $\forall C \ (A\cup C = B \cup C)$ implies in particular $A \cup \emptyset = B \cup \emptyset$.

$$\forall A \ \forall B \ \forall C \ \underbrace{\big((A\cup C = B \cup C) \to A=B\big)}_{\textrm{scope }}$$
This second formula does not hold since here $\big((A\cup C = B \cup C) \to A=B\big)$ is required to hold for any $A,B,C$. eg take $A\neq B$ and $C:=A \cup B$, then $(A\cup C = B \cup C)$ holds but $A=B$ doesn't hold.

Comment: @OlivierRoche.- I'm trying to understand your answer. Would you say that: A and B being 2 sets whatever, if for all set C , "A U C = B U C" is true , then A and B have to be equal to the empty set; and hence are equal. It seems to me that the emptyness of both A and B is a necessary condition for the antecedent to be true ( which would explain why the whole conditional holds).

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames "If for all set C , '$A\cup C = B\cup C$' is true, then $A$ and $B$ have to be equal to the empty set"  No!  Let me ask you... is $A\cup C = A\cup C$ always true?  Yes.  Both the expression on the left and the expression on the right are identical.  Now... given that $\color{blue}{A}=\color{red}{A}$ then $\color{blue}{A}\cup C = \color{red}{A}\cup C$ is also always true, yes?  Yes.  Now, consider what happens when $A=B$.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames nowhere in that line of logic did we require that $A$ and $B$ be non-empty.  If $A=B=\{42,1729\}$, then $A\cup C = \{42,1729\}\cup C = B\cup C$ regardless what $C$ is...